# Different implicit definitions

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm Dutch, and my books are written in Dutch, so appologies if technical terms are incorrectly translated.

1. $\in$ means 'element of'
2. $\mathbb{Z}$ is the set of 'whole numbers'
3. $\leq$ is 'less than or equal to'

   - $V = \{x \in\mathbb{Z} ~~|~~x \text{ is even}\}$
   - $W = \{x \in\mathbb{Z} ~~|~~ x^3 < 0 \text{ and } -10 \leq -2x \leq 20\}$
   - $X = \{x ~~|~~ x = v + w \text{ for some } v \in V \text{ and } w \in W\}$

I am asked to give an explicit definition for $X$, or if that's impossible give a different implicit one. Since I'd have to go over an infinite amount of numbers in $V$ to give an explicit definition, I'm pretty sure that's impossible. But what would a different implicit definition look like?

On a side note (if that's ok) I find $W$ confusing, because it seems to me it can only contain $-10$ through $-1$ yet the implicit definition defines "$\leq 20$" - is that just to put me off or did I miss something?

This is my first question here so sorry if I broke some conventions.

Comment: Welcome. You can make your question look nicer by using better symbols. You can type \in to get the usual $\in$ thing, instead of "E". Some people are more likely to answer a question if it looks nice.

Comment: Never mind. Eric did it for you.

Comment: @natli: I've reformatted your question to include the symbols. If you want to keep asking questions here, you should take some time to fiddle around with the changes I made. So you can use them in the future.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think there would be formatting options for such  specific things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that $W$ is defined in a silly way. But you figured it out correctly, so that is good :)

Suppose that $n$ is an even number. Then $n,~n+2,~n-2,~n+4,~n-4,\dots$ are all in $V$. Can you use this to show that $n$ is also in $X$?

Suppose that $m$ is an odd number. Then $m+1,~m-1,~m+3,~m-3, \dots$ are all in $V$. A similar trick will show that $m$ is in $X$.

Comment: Does $\mathbb{X}$ just become equal to $\mathbb{V}$ minus the 'even' restriction, so basically just $\mathbb{Z}$? Because if I were to pick the number 220 from $\mathbb{V}$, one of it's values in $\mathbb{X}$ would be `220 + -1`, which is 119 so since that goes for all numbers in $\mathbb{V}$ I think I just end up with $\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Yes, your answer is correct. But this problem has a lot of tricks, and your *solution* has hit the last and nastiest one: it is tempting to say, "Oh yes, we have hit all of the things in $\mathbb{Z}$ that are not in $X$, so we are done." But this is only true if $0\in W$, which it is not. For example, if $W=\{-1\}$ (with no other elements), then $v+w$ would always be odd, and so $X$ would be only odd integers. So, your argument shows that $X$ contains all odds, but why does it contain all evens? (It's not hard, but you have to say something)

Comment: Since $\mathbb{W}$ also contains -2 it should also pick up all evens, correct?

Comment: yep :) Now you're done. [Also, your english is remarkable. As someone who has failed to learn multiple languages, congratulations!]

Comment: Sweet, thanks for the lesson (and compliment ;D). For the definition, do I have to state X = $\{x \in\mathbb{Z}\}$ or can I just say $\mathbb{X} = \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: I would just say $X=\mathbb{Z}$. The other one is the same thing and it's harder to read.